# Right-align attribute aliases in QGIS attribute forms

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-form

I have an attribute form created with QGIS 'Drag and drop Designer' that looks like this:

[image]

As can be seen, the attribute aliases (the labels on the left) are little longer because of some explanatory text in the round brackets.

It might be a matter of taste and a matter of readability as well, but is there a way to right-align theses labels to make them stand near the related input widet? Can this be achieved with QGIS standard tools or do I have to create an ui file with the QtDesigner?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a matter of taste, but a matter of readability. But I think you should use abbreviations first, e.g. "Lfd.Nr. (straßenbez.)", "Drehung (UZS, 0=N)[°]" or "Höhe [m]". Then reassess the need for alignment?

Comment: @Erik An approach worth discussing with the customer.

Comment: For me, you have to do it under QtDesigner, but it's very simple if the fields have same names as the `atlas_punkte` table. Maybe, if the fields names are always the same, rename other fields with spaces before to simulate a right align ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that makes use of a python function that is called when the dialog opens:

[image]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLineEdit, QLabel
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt

def atlas_punkte_init_values(dialog, layer, feature):
    labels_to_align = ['hoehe_druck', 'breite_druck', 'rot_druck', 'scale_druck']
    labels = dialog.findChildren(QLabel)
    for l in labels:
        try:
            l.setAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)
            if l.buddy().objectName() in labels_to_align:
                l.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        except:
            pass
```

By providing a list of attribute names the labels can be aligned selectively, and the use of `Qt.AlignVCenter` makes the alignment look even fancier (try it without :-)

Result (note the labels in the 'Druck'-box):

[image]

By accessing the methods of `QLabel` each kind of style modification should be possible in the attribute form labels (and other elements).